# How to stop browser tab change event in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have working on popup show using JavaScript in my browser when user change browser tabs. I have following solution to show popup while changing browser tabs. Its working fine.

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function(e) {

    if (document.hidden){
        alert("popup module");
    }
});
```

I need to stop user to change browser tabs.

Comment: "I need to stop user to change browser tabs." — Users need you to be unable to do that.

Comment: No browser worth it's salt is going to let you do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. Browsers don't allow stuff like that because it could be used to keep you on a malicious website. What are you even trying to accomplish? Maybe there's a workaround.

Comment: You don't need a workaround ... these aren't the droids you're looking for ... you can go about your business ... move along

Answer (score 0):

Just put this on console

`window.open=null`